# Ruby- Mysql2 Client returning empty results

Tags: sql, ruby, mysql2

I have an SQL query that I run on Heidi SQL 9.1.  It works fine and returns about 100 lines in 30 seconds.

I try to do this same query in ruby.  When I try simple queries like

```
select * from tiny_table limit 1
```

It works fine.  But when I run my main query via ruby using Mysql2 and the following:

```
gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('my_ssh',nil)
port = gateway.open("127.0.0.1",3306,3307)
client = Mysql2::Client.new(
host: "127.0.0.1",
username: '*****',
password: '****',
database: 'db',
port: port
)
data = client.query(" MY QUERY " )



data.each do |row|
    puts "#{row}"
end
```

I get nothing because data = {}

Why is Msql2 client returning nothing all the time?

Comment: I'd recommend *NOT* using the driver to talk to the database. Instead, step up one level and use an ORM. It will protect you in many ways, plus will make your life a lot easier in the long run. If you're not using Rails I'd recommend looking at [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel).

Comment: Thank you Tin Man.  I've been thinking about using an ORM for a lot of reasons.   That said I'm still wondering why this gem is returning an empty hash instead of the query results.

Comment: Agreed with the above comment, using an ORM will make things a lot easier. ActiveRecord is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, I'm implementing that now.  But I still don't have an answer to the original question.

Comment: We can't tell you why your query is returning nothing because we don't know what your query is. Nor do we know what your schema is. Nor do we know what data you have in the table. It's important to give us enough information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear.  The query returns results when I run it directly in my client (Heidi 9.1)

But when I run that same query using  Mysql2 client it returns nothing.